# Як утворились слова «типізація» і «шипування»

Tags: словотворення, суфікси

Чому *типізація*, а не *типування*? Адже ми не кажемо *шипізація*, а кажемо *шипування*.

Наскільки я розумію, то *-ізація* це переклад англійського *[-ization](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ization#English)*:

> Суфікс, що утворює іменники, які позначають дію, процес або результат дії, або вироблення чогось.

На [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) маємо як варіанти *typing* і *typization*:

> **typing** = система типів, типізація; набирання з клавіатури:
>   **типіза́ція, -ції** = typization, standardization

---

Гмм... Щойно натрапив на слово *routing*, і мені спало на думку подивитись, як його перекладають. Ось, що я знайшов на [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=routing&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on).

1. Великий англо-український словник 2011 (Є.І. Гороть, Л.М. Коцюк, Л.К. Малімон, А.Б. Павлюк.)

> **routing** [ˈru:tɪŋ] *n*
>   1. траса; курс;
>   2. тех. схема руху; маршрутизація;
>   3. ...

2. Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010 (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)

> **routing** = ['ru:tɪŋ] маршрутува́ння; трасува́ння

Виходить, що можна і так, і так? Питання лише в тому, який варіант усталився? Але чому наразі маємо різні варіанти, і якому варто віддавати перевагу?